# Functions and unions on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I seek an elementary set theory proof. (All new to me.)

Let $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ be a function. $A_i$ are subsets of $X$, $B_i$ are subsets of $Y$.

Prove that $f\left(\bigcup_iA_i\right) = \bigcup_if(A_i)$

I sense that the approach is to show they're subsets of each other, but I can't out how to formulate this.

(Whilst we're at it, is the same true with the intersection?)

Answer (score 1):

$$y \in f\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right) \quad \iff \quad \exists i,\ \exists x \in A_i,\ y=f(x) \quad \iff \quad y \in \bigcup_i f(A_i).$$

This is not true for intersection. Consider $f(x) = x^2$, $A_1 = (-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, +\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks @njguliyev. I new to math/set theory and need some help understanding: Is this to say that for an element $y$ of $f(\cup_iA_i)$ there's an $x$ element of a set $A_i$ such that $f(x) = y$, and that y must also be an element of $U_i f(A_i)$?